# Unity3d ragdoll gravity issue?

Tags: unity, physics

[image]
I was following [AnimFollow tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=166&v=Hw1UK85sARc) to learn how to rag without using any script from it. I found issue with gravity. When I hit play button and animator is enabled character stay on air and play idle animation. If I disabled animator character fall down and all human parts moving. If I enabled again animator character get back to air position with idle animation playing. My issue is when character stay on air for 2 seconds, he fall down stronger than one second !! And if he stay for long time on air, the fall becomes more stronger !! Rigidbody settings for all parties [Mass = 1 , Drug = 0 , Angular Drag = 1] How to solve this ? why gravity is increase ?

Comment: It's likely that gravity isn't increasing, but velocity is. Each frame, gravity is accumulating into the downward velocity, but then the physics engine is blocked from moving the object using that velocity because the animator has control of its root motion. So the velocity variable increases without any visible effect on screen. Until the physics gets an opportunity to move it for real and all that stored velocity kicks in all at once.

Comment: Good to know that. So, how to solve this ? which steps should I take ?

Comment: Your question above already asks that. You don't need to ask again in the comments. If someone knows, they'll post an answer.